sql select statement in vba not pulling headers from excel closed workbook and some other values
I am working with excel workbook to pull data of my closed workbook "RawData.xlsm" sheet name "all_register". following are the code, but this vba code unable to pull all headers (first rows/ columns names) as well as some cells values (value cell format is "General"
Option Explicit

Sub GetDataFromClosedFile()

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    
    cn.ConnectionString = _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "/RawData.xlsm;" & _
        "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=NO';"    

    cn.Open
    
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    
    rs.ActiveConnection = cn
    rs.Source = "SELECT * FROM [all_register$]"
    rs.Open
    
    Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
    
    Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
    rs.Close
        
    cn.Close
    
End Sub

with this code some headers showed some not due to mismatch of column data with header (e.g header heading is "date" and below data is date like 23/7/2024.
need expert attention to correct my code.
I am not expert in VBA, try easy way in your expert advice

HDR=NO means without headers. You should use HDR=Yes. Now, what does "as well as some cells values" mean? I will also suggest to replace your connection string last line with "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes""". And use a separate line for provider: cn.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" followed  by cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=""" & _ ThisWorkbook.Path & "/RawData.xlsm""";" & _ "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes""". Of course, new lines after _...

my Source file have headers, and want to show headers in my destination file, for this I think I should use HDR=NO , by using above suggestion same result, some columns headers pulled some not, Header name PERCENTAGE, and data under this header is Fraction e.g 1/10 or 1/16

Your connection string specifies that headers should not be received, change HDR to YES
    cn.ConnectionString = _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "/RawData.xlsm;" & _
        "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES';" 


still no success, Header name PERCENTAGE , and data under this header is Fraction e.g 1/10 or 1/16. Header name INCOME , data under this header is formated as Number (e.g 1000 or 20000)
